# How do I go about making custom minimize, maximize, and close buttons with pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm creating a game in [pygame](/questions/tagged/pygame), and I want to add custom buttons for minimizing, maximizing, and closing a window, similar to the discord desktop application

Comment: Note that I *have* done multiple google searches for this, so I'm completely in the dark.

Comment: Please provide a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Answer (score 2):

Pygame is not really suited for that task.

Here's a running example:

```
import pygame
import pygame.freetype

import ctypes
user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32')
SW_MAXIMISE = 3
SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1

def main():
    pygame.init()
    flags = pygame.RESIZABLE
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500), flags)
    hWnd = user32.GetForegroundWindow()
    orgsize = None 

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    min = pygame.Rect((0, 16, 32, 32))
    max = pygame.Rect((0, 16, 32, 32))
    close = pygame.Rect((0, 16, 32, 32))

    min.right = screen.get_rect().right - 90
    max.right = screen.get_rect().right - 50
    close.right = screen.get_rect().right - 10

    font = pygame.freetype.SysFont(None, 32)
    font.origin = True
    while True:
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            if e.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
                screen = pygame.display.set_mode((e.w, e.h), flags)
                min.right = screen.get_rect().right - 90
                max.right = screen.get_rect().right - 50
                close.right = screen.get_rect().right - 10
            if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                if close.collidepoint(pos):
                    return
                if min.collidepoint(pos):
                    pygame.display.iconify()
                if max.collidepoint(pos):
                    if not orgsize:
                        orgsize = screen.get_rect().size
                        user32.ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_MAXIMISE)
                    else:
                        user32.ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL)
                        screen = pygame.display.set_mode(orgsize, flags)
                        orgsize = None

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.Color('dodgerblue'), max)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.Color('darkorange'), min)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.Color('darkred'), close)
        font.render_to(screen, min.move(7, -10).bottomleft, '_')
        font.render_to(screen, max.move(4, -5).bottomleft, 'O')
        font.render_to(screen, close.move(4, -5).bottomleft, 'X')
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pygame.quit()
```

Minimizing is easy: just call `pygame.display.iconify()`.

Closing is easy, too: just quit your main loop.

Maximizing is not that easy: to have it to work, you need a resizable window, which will not work with a frameless window (at least on Windows). Also, the code to maximize a window is also platform specific. My example above will only work on Windows, as it uses the user32.dll.

Instead of maximizing, you could switch to fullscreen mode, so you don't have to use platfrom specific code and you don't have to bother with resolution changes.

Comment: Exactly, Not to mention all the edge cases you would need to do if you were i dunno, hardcoding position values into the code.

Comment: So something I should have noted in the post is this:
I'm using linux, and I saw WinDLL